# backslash and dot in enumeration

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I try to modify my enumeration list by using the `enumitem` package. The desired out put is a list of 1\. item, 2\. item, and so on. I tried the following

mwe1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*\backslash\dot}]
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

mwe2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*\backslash .}]
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

but non of them work.

Comment: `\backslash` and `\dot` are math commands (and `\dot` takes an argument: `\dot{x}`). Try `\textbackslash.`.

Comment: that's solves the problem. i thought that both of them can be used in text as well. could you provide a more complete answer for future reference?

Comment: Done :-) (and more characters)

Comment: Why the backslash? Is that really common somewhere?

Comment: no. i would say that it's rather unusual, but more a matter of personal interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get from either of your examples is:

```latex
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 \item 1

?
```

which (usually) means that TeX found a math command in text mode, while processing `\item 1`. The guilty command here is `\backslash`, because it's a math delimiter defined (in `fontmath.ltx`) as:

```latex
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\backslash}
   {\mathord}{symbols}{"6E}{largesymbols}{"0F}
```

you can replace that by some text command, like `\textbackslash`.

If you do that, the second example will work, while the first will still produce the same error. The guilty command now is `\dot`, which is used to place a dot over a variable, like in `\dot{x}` to produce *`ẋ`* (it also takes an argument, so if you try to use `label={\arabic*$\backslash\dot$}`, TeX will throw yet another error). Here you can simply use the character `.`.

Working MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*\textbackslash .}]
\item 1
\item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```